# Building live555 Streaming Media in Windows result in .obj files, not .a

Tags: build, makefile, live555

I'm trying to stream rtsp video via tcp using mplayer in windows minGW shell and it depends on live555 streaming media library.
The steps I did are:

- download the live555 streaming media src
- build each .mak files in src/live/ (I use `nmake /f *.mak` via command line, because my VS2010 can't recognize the .mak files.)

Building process was success and the result are `.obj` files. The problem is mplayer need `.a` files to make and the build didn't create it.

My question is:

- do I really need the .a files? If so, how do I get it?
- is there any other build method I can use to solve this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

Do I need .a files?

- Yes, I need them.

How to get it?

- run `./genMakeFiles mingw` in `src/live/` from MinGW
- run `make`

Answer (score -1):

run ./genMakefiles

run  make

you can refer below link

http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/